# Sql Azure - Calculate remaining DTU limit of each server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have multiple Sql-Azure Servers on which i allow users to create multiple databases. Since these servers have a maximum allowed DTU limit, I wanted to add an alert on the remaining DTU's which a server has..

For example, A server X has maximum DTU Quota of 100 and i create 3 databases db1 (dtu limit 10), db2 (dtu limit 5) and db3 (dtu limit 5).. Then i want to emit out a metric saying server X has a pending quota of 80.

I want to query this data from SQL Azure and not rely on my internal structures to emit this alert..

Comment: If I remember the DTU is at the database level. There's no such thing as Database Server DTU. Would you mind sharing a link which talks about Server DTU?

Comment: Gaurev is right, Servers are effectively just arbitrary labels that allows you to group databases to manage them together. I think they do have a total quota, but it's arbitrary as doesn't affect costs. It would probably be easier to just create a server per database for your scenario? Elastic Pools is the only thing that shares DTU between databases, but they work completely differently.

Comment: @Frans - If you look under provisioning servers, they have an overall DTU limit. We have run into errors where the overall DTUs per servers have also run out.

Comment: @Arun, yeah, I know. The point is, it's sort of an arbitrary limit. Is there any reason you can't just create a server per database? In any case, if you do need this, PowerShell May be the answer. I'm not at a PC right now so can't check.

Comment: @Frans.. Actually we have a PAAS solution. Whenever user creates a resource in our system.. We internally as a part of creating a resource, create a meta store for him. I was not able to find any API in public domain which does that - But in the azure portal i saw some web api's which did just that [again those where not documented]

Comment: @ArunKhetarpal Makes sense; multi-tenant. You want the Azure REST Api or the Azure Management Libraries if you use .Net (they are just a wrapper for the REST API). Sadly, the docs are a complete train wreck; I've just spent an hour not even getting auth to work. But, with patience you can get there - I know I did get it to work once.   As an aside if you are creating a DB per tenant, you really want to look at Elastic Pools, they could save you a lot of money (they were introduced for exactly this kind of scenario).